# Passing extras with Intent.createChooser

Tags: android

I am using following code to select picture from gallery. I want to track the int value from this intent.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
intent.putExtra("Position", 1)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE)
```

But I am getting only default value[0] when trying to get the passed value from intent in onActivityResult.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            val selectedImageURI = data?.data
            val position = data?.getIntExtra("Position", 0)
        }
    }
}
```

So my doubt is, is it possible to track the values through intent chooser? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to track the values through intent chooser?

No. Your problem has nothing to do with the chooser. You would have the same results with `startActivityForResult(intent), SELECT_PICTURE)`.

There is no requirement for the activity being started by `startActivityForResult()` to return to you any extras that you happen to have put in that `Intent`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `requestCode` in this line:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), requestCode)
// for example use SELECT_PICTURE_POSITION_1 as requestCode
```

then you get it back here:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        when (requestCode) {// use your request code here
            SELECT_PICTURE_POSITION_0 -> {
                          val selectedImageURI = data?.data
                          val position = data?.getIntExtra("Position", 0)
            }
            SELECT_PICTURE_POSITION_1 -> {
                          val selectedImageURI = data?.data
                          val position = data?.getIntExtra("Position", 1)
            }
            SELECT_PICTURE_POSITION_2 -> {
                          val selectedImageURI = data?.data
                          val position = data?.getIntExtra("Position", 2)
            }
            //other conditions here
        }
    }
}
```

use multiple request codes for your needs.